# Proving real inclusion for $1 \leq p \lt r \lt \infty$

Tags: normed-spaces, inclusion-exclusion

How can I show for $1 \leq p \lt  r \lt \infty$ that there is the real inclusion

{${x \in \mathbb{R^n}: \left\lVert x \right\rVert_p \leq 1} $} $\subsetneq$ {$x \in \mathbb{R^n}: \left\lVert x \right\rVert_r \leq 1  $}.

I know that there is a real inclusion, if there is $A \subseteq B $ and $A \neq B$, but I don't really know much further..

Comment: To prove that the sets are not equal, you can use the point $x = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt[r] n}, \ldots , \frac{1}{\sqrt[r] n} \right)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For the inclusion, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893224/if-1-leq-p-r-leq-infty-then-x-p-geq-x-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be useful.